# Youtube API: Search videos playable on mobile devices

Tags: java, android, api, youtube

I'm using the youtube api to query by keyword for videos. The result has to be playable on Android Youtube App, but sometimes i'm getting an error that the video is not available on mobile devices.

Is there a parameter / option to search for videos that are playable on mobile devices?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see in:
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters.html
You can specify a format parameter for your query.

```
1   RTSP streaming URL for mobile video playback. H.263 video (up to 176x144) and AMR audio.
5   HTTP URL to the embeddable player (SWF) for this video. This format is not available for a video that is not embeddable. Developers commonly add &format=5 to their queries to restrict results to videos that can be embedded on their sites.
6   RTSP streaming URL for mobile video playback. MPEG-4 SP video (up to 176x144) and AAC audio.
```

Comment: Do you know which format should be the correct one for the Android youtube app?

Comment: Some up-votes would be appreciated for the work I've done... Process of elimination: H.263 is more compressed than MPEG-4. So go with 1