# How to check if youTube video is 'playable' on the iPhone

Tags: ios, permissions, youtube, playback

I am maintaing both an iPhone and web version for my application. Hence there are times when I embed a youTube video on the web which is unplayable on the iPhone (see iPhone screenshot below)

[image]

How can I do a check for such videos which cannot be played on the iPhone so that I can trigger a message to tell users to view the video on the web instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Youtube API: Search videos playable on mobile devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422434/youtube-api-search-videos-playable-on-mobile-devices)

Comment: Does it make a difference that I am not searching videos but instead checking the permission of existing embedded videos. Also I am not using gdata.

Comment: Hey if you got any answer please let me know i am facing the same problem.