# How to only find videos that can be played on mobile?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Does YouTube data API still not support this feature?
I have been trying to find a way for more than a few months already, and there doesn't seem to be a reliable way to retrieve a list of video that can be absolutely played without restrictions on a certain device. An answer from a person who's involved in the team would be VERY appreciated.

[Youtube API: Search videos playable on mobile devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422434/youtube-api-search-videos-playable-on-mobile-devices) might be relevant, but I am skeptical whether this approach can be used to solve "The content owner prohibited this video to be played on this platform" type of restrictions.

**Update:**
On Nov, 7, 2015, there is still no way to filter the videos that are playable on a mobile device. More specifically, I want to find the videos that are playable on an embedded iFrame (ex. [iOS helper library](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper)) using the [YouTube data api v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/). The available params for a search query are listed [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Youtube API: Search videos playable on mobile devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422434/youtube-api-search-videos-playable-on-mobile-devices)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. This question specifically asks for the videos that can be played on a mobile device, not because of the format issue, but because of the restrictions set by video authors.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003041/retrive-only-mobile-supported-video-from-youtube-api/19008571#19008571

Comment: Look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003041/retrive-only-mobile-supported-video-from-youtube-api/19008571#19008571

Comment: Although @IbrahimUlukaya's answer is mostly correct, the query is still flawed.  I've set up a query with `videoEmbeddable` and `videoSyndicated` equal to true but have had TV episodes such as Twister (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kSdbE5uxINs) returned.  This episode is playable on the YouTube mobile app, but not in the embedded iFrame player (like in a webview on iOS, etc).  The query doesn't work as intended, something is wrong on YouTube's end.

Comment: I have already looked at all the related links but haven't been able to find the answer that I want, like @JAL said. Should I report a bug report?

Comment: @MaximusS: Have you reported the bug already? IMHO, the only viable solution, for now, is to stream the videos from YT towards a server of yours, then to the user, so you can forgive all YT-imposed restrictions inside the server; I'm not sure how legal and costly would be that, thought... Or you could make the app fake the YT server and not actually tell it that it's running on a mobile device.

Answer (score 2):

You can find various search parameter listed in [YouTube API v2.0 – API Query Parameters](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters?csw=1) like `license`, `restriction`, `paid_content` that can help filter videos that are restricted for such specific reason. Also, if you can use [YouTube API v3.0](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) there is one more option `videoSyndicated` that will restrict a search to only videos that can be played outside youtube.com.

Comment: This answer is out of question asked.

Comment: @Dharmesh Patel you left out the most critical parts of the answer. v2 is deprecated, use the v3 API.  When you hit the Search/list endpoint, you should set videoEmbeddable and videoSyndicated to true.